# Solving ODE with Python reversely

Tags: python, ode

In Python we solve a differential equation `OD_H` with an initial point `y0 = od0` in a specific point `z` similar to the following code

```
def OD_H(od, z, c, b):
   ....
   return ....

od = solve_ivp(lambda od, z: OD_H(od, z, c, b), t_span = [z1, z], y0 = [od0])['y'][-1][-1]
```

or

```
od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [0, z], args=(c, b))[-1]
```

So we have

`answer of ODE OD_H(y0 = 0.69, z=0.153) = 0.59`

My question is,

Now If I have the answer of `OD_H = 0.59` and `y0 = 0.69`, how could I obtain `z`? It should be `0.153` but consider we don't know its value and we cannot do trial and error to find it.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your target a specific value of the derivatives function or of the solution? With the long intro I'm not sure if it is really the first. The answer in both cases is "intelligent trial-and-error", also called a numerical non-linear solver. scipy.optimize.fsolve (?) could be used. In the second case also a boundary value solver or the event mechanism of solve_ivp.

Comment: @lutzl I want to obtain `z`. We have `dh/dz` so we choose one `z` to find the value at that point. Now I have the answer but I dont know in which `z`.

Comment: The first can be done via `z=scipy.optimze.fsolve(lambda vz: OD_H(y0,vz,c,b), 0)`.

Comment: @lutzl  I have three question. 1.Could you tell me please, what is `0` at the end of line? 2. And do you know how to write this code for `odeint` (second code) 3. This code you wrote give me the `z` in which we find the value `0.59`

Comment: @lutzl I mean where is `0.59`

Comment: fsolve needs an initial guess, I set `z0=0` And yes, you need to subtract the target value, `z=scipy.optimze.fsolve(lambda vz: OD_H(y0,vz,c,b)-target, 0)`. With odeint you can compute a solution and check where it passes the given value, and refine via interpolation. A crude method is to apply fsolve to `lambda vz: odeint(OD_H,  y0, [0,vz])[-1,0]-target`. This is expensive as that integrates over each function call, while using the event mechanism of solve_ivp only one integration is needed.

Comment: @lutzl target is `0.59` or answer of ODE?

Comment: Yes, `target` is the target value, `0.59` is the only one given in the question. It is still not completely clear what exactly you want to compute. How would you test that the value returned by the solver is actually a solution? Given that forward problem, it is easier to identify how to solve the correct inverse problem.

Comment: @lutzl if this way you wrote gives me the value of `z` in which we found the answer of ODE (dh/dz) it is correct. Well,  in normal way, we solve it and  choosing range of `z`  we can have plot the value of `h` in terms of `z`.  Now you consider you have values of `h` but you dont know the value of z. The only thing you know is initial point and value of ode which is h. So with this way you will fin z and you will plot h_z

Comment: @lutzl  I have one other question. What is `vz`? I do not have it.

Comment: That is the lambda-local value of the variable `z`. You should not need it, as its scope is the lambda expression, where it is also declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are proposing a root problem where the solver function evaluated minus the desired answer is the function f(x) where f(x)=0.
Because ODE solver returns point arrays and not callable functions, you need to interpolate first the solution points. Then, this is used in root finding problem.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp # Recommended initival value problem solver
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d # 1D interpolation
from scipy.optimize import brentq # Root finding method in an interval
exponential_decay = lambda t, y: -0.5 * y # dy/dt = f(t, y)
t_span = [0, 10] # Interval of integration
y0 = [2] # Initial state: y(t=t_span[0])=2
desired_answer = 0.59
sol_ode = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, t_span, y0) # IVP solution
f_sol_ode = interp1d(sol_ode.t, sol_ode.y) # Build interpolated function
brentq(lambda x: f_sol_ode(x) - desired_answer, t_span[0], t_span[1])
```

Comment: U dont know this one. Just I know we have initial point, we have the answer of ODE but we do not have z, the point in which the results is obtained.

Comment: Exactly, x is that point, as a variable of the callable function that you need to create with the ODE solver. In abstract form, f(z) = your_ode_solver(args, z) - 0.59. Then, the root finding method iterate over z until f(z) approach to zero. When this occur, the z value returned by the root finding method is the point where the solution function of the ODE evalueted is 0.59.

Comment: Could I ask you to write the code if your answer exactly is what I want please? Thank you so much.

Comment: `exponential_decay = lambda t, y: -0.5 * y # dy/dt = f(t, y)`  is it possible to consider this one? `exponential_decay = lambda t, y: (-0.5 * y)/(1+t)`

Comment: This is right, you can test any function that depends of `t` and `y`.

Comment: Only you need to pay attention in one thing. Root finding method is dependent of the function. `brentq`works if the function changes the sign, but in other cases you need a method with one guess (as `newton`). In case of `newton`, because the search is in open interval, the interpolated function could fail (a value requested outside of the integration interval).

Comment: Also, there is no way to know if the desired value no exists with code. If you put a value that is not posible as ODE solution, the code fails. You can try to plot `sol_ode.t` and `sol_ode.y` to verify.

Comment: I am sure that `z` should be less than 1 and bigger than 0. So let me run the code once.

Comment: In what ODE? If you use `(-0.5 * y)/(1+t)` in the interval [0, 10] with initial value 2, you need 0.61 < `z` < 2.0.

Comment: No, in my model. this is just a sample. I am ganna run the code now.

Comment: wonderful, it works. But one question. it is very close to answer but with errors (I mean sigma) or answer plus/minus something. For example I expect to reach 0.98 but it shows 0.89

Comment: `ValueError: f(a) and f(b) must have different signs` do you kknow how to pas this error?

Comment: Give me your differential equation. That error is because the solution function could have a critical point or because your target value is not part of the range of the solution.

Comment: could I email you the python file and the data file please?

Comment: Have you dropbox or other cloud storage? Post your URL in comment or in question. Also, you can add the equation as image.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x128fw1gbg1m9n2/AAADqc_J6Yjg207zwpGpU8qga?dl=0  Please let me know if you able to open it. Thank you. the error is `ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.`

Comment: I think I have to share the folder with you. You can not open it right now. I think. Could I send it to your email Address, please? it is important to me. Thank you

Comment: The problem is because `odr[i]` is lesser than the minimun of the solution https://screenshots.firefox.com/18zQqsfdGSvNmLkF/localhost . Error in odr or numerical error propagating in ODE solution.