# Figure out parameter in ordinary differential equation when some data provided

Tags: python, parameters, ode

Code:

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters

S = 0.0001
M = 30.03
K = 113.6561
Vr = 58
R = 8.3145
T = 298.15
Q = 0.000133
Vp = 0.000022
Mr = 36
Pvap = 1400
wf = 0.001
tr = 1200
mass = 40000

# define t
time = 14400
t = np.arange(0, time + 1, 1)

# define initial state
Cv0 = (mass / Vp) * wf  # Cv(0)
Cr0 = (mass / Vp) * (1 - wf)
Cair0 = 0  # Cair(0)


# define function and solve ode
def model(x, t):
    C = x[0]  # C is Cair(t)
    c = x[1]  # c is Cv(t)
    a = Q + (K * S / Vr)
    b = (K * S * M) / (Vr * R * T)
    s = (K * S * M) / (Vp * R * T)
    w = (1 - wf) * 1000
    Peq = (c * Pvap) / (c + w * c * M / Mr)
    Pair = (C * R * T) / M
    dcdt = -s * (Peq - Pair)
    if t <= tr:
        dCdt = -a * C + b * Peq
    else:
        dCdt = -a * C
    return [dCdt, dcdt]

x = odeint(model, [Cair0, Cv0], t)

C = x[:, 0]
c = x[:, 1]
```

Now, I want to figure out `wf` value when I know C(0)(when t is 0) and C(tr)(when t is tr)(Therefore I know two kind of t and C(t)).

I found some links([Curve Fit Parameters in Multiple ODE Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011675/curve-fit-parameters-in-multiple-ode-function), [Solving ODE with Python reversely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54161375/solving-ode-with-python-reversely), https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/coronavirus-in-italy-ode-model-an-parameter-optimization-forecast-with-python-c1769cf7a511, https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/18/Fitting-a-numerical-ODE-solution-to-data/) related to this, although I cannot get the hang of subject.

Can I fine parameter wf with two `data((0, C(0)), (tr, C(tr))` and ode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ODE solvers assume smooth right-hand-side functions. So the `if t <= tr:`... statement in your code isn't going to work. Two separate integrations must be done to deal with the discontinuity. Integrate to `tf`, then use the solution at tf as initial conditions to integrate beyond `tf` for the new ODE function.

But it seems like your main problem (solving for `wf`) only involves integrating to `tf` (not beyond), so we can ignore that issue when solving for `wf`

> Now, I want to figure out wf value when I know C(0)(when t is 0) and C(tr)(when t is tr)(Therefore I know two kind of t and C(t)).

You can do a non-linear solve for `wf`:

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters
S = 0.0001
M = 30.03
K = 113.6561
Vr = 58
R = 8.3145
T = 298.15
Q = 0.000133
Vp = 0.000022
Mr = 36
Pvap = 1400
mass = 40000

# initial condition for wf
wf_initial = 0.02

# define t
tr = 1200
t_eval = np.array([0, tr], np.float)

# define initial state. This is C(t = 0)
Cv0 = (mass / Vp) * wf_initial  # Cv(0)
Cair0 = 0  # Cair(0)
init_cond = np.array([Cair0, Cv0],np.float)

# Definte the final state. This is C(t = tr)
final_state = 3.94926615e-03

# define function and solve ode
def model(x, t, wf):
    C = x[0]  # C is Cair(t)
    c = x[1]  # c is Cv(t)
    a = Q + (K * S / Vr)
    b = (K * S * M) / (Vr * R * T)
    s = (K * S * M) / (Vp * R * T)
    w = (1 - wf) * 1000
    Peq = (c * Pvap) / (c + w * c * M / Mr)
    Pair = (C * R * T) / M
    dcdt = -s * (Peq - Pair)
    dCdt = -a * C + b * Peq
    return [dCdt, dcdt]

# define non-linear system to solve
def function(x):
    wf = x[0]
    x = odeint(model, init_cond, t_eval, args = (wf,), rtol = 1e-10, atol = 1e-10)    
    return x[-1,0] - final_state

from scipy.optimize import root
sol = root(function, np.array([wf_initial]),  method='lm')

print(sol.success)

wf_solution = sol.x[0]
x = odeint(model, init_cond, t_eval, args = (wf_solution,), rtol = 1e-10, atol = 1e-10)

print(wf_solution)
print(x[-1])
print(final_state)
```

Comment: Thanks. So, I can solve wf when t is not bigger than tr, right? If I want to solve wf when t is bigger than tr, just modify function defined?

Comment: If I want to solve wf when t is bigger than tr, then you must do two integrations in the function defining your non-linear system. Do the first integration up to t = tr, then use the solution at t = tr as intial conditions for a new integration, with a new ODE function (`dCdt = -a * C`)

Comment: Wait. Do the first integration up to t = tr without wf ???

Comment: Actually, I try to solve wf when t is bigger than tr with your advice, but wf value differ only in differ of wf_initial.

Comment: Oh. I know it! wf is not a parameter of dCdt = -a * C !!!! wf is independent of this equation!!! Therefore wf value differ only in differ of wf_initial!!!